# difference between reversible and irreversible entropy

Tags: entropy, work

Before I proceed, let me first say I have done research and understand the general idea between the two: summed up crudely reversible happens in a slower continuous manner while irreversible happens immediately due to a sudden change in conditions. Or mathematically, I suppose you could say the irreversible change isn't continuous and therefore the entropy formula is not integratabtle.

But I was given an example of a box with a partition and gas in only one chamber. The removal of the partition and the expansion of the gas is a form of irreversible entropy because the gas fills the chamber almost instantaneously.

So I'm left with the question: what if the partition doesn't disappear but is simply disconnected from the walls and the gas is able to push the wall as if the gas was doing work on a piston. This would then be seen as reversible correct? As you would be able to see the partition move in a continuous path across the box.

If I am correct in my beliefs up to this point, then...

What if the partition is made the size of an atom, wouldn't work still be done on the atom? Wouldn't it still take a continuous path across the box? So is this reversible or irreversible?

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics)? The difference between reversible and irreversible processes is not how fast they happen but if the system is always in equilibrium, or not. In the mixing example it doesn't matter how slowly the mixing occurs, the system is never in equilibrium. If you don't remove the partition, that's a different system, altogether, that has nothing to do with the mixing system.

Comment: Unless the system does the maximum amount of work that it can, the process will still be irreversible. Thus you need to attach the partition to a weight that will exactly balance the force exerted by the gas on the partition, then very slowly start to remove small parts of the weight. In general any spontaneous process that occurs due to a finite difference in temperature, pressure, density, etc. will be irreversible.